# Migration from REST to Graph: Refreshed token throws InvalidAuthenticationToken

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been struggling for hours with this so my last resort is asking for some help.

We need to ensure that the old tokens issued in our system are still valid once we migrate to Graph. Tokens are successfully refreshed using the refres_token issued by the REST API, but when I try to use the issued token to make a call I'm getting the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A",
"innerError": {
"date": "2022-09-15T22:19:58",
"request-id": "fceadbcd-d55a-4bee-b2a9-fca6828053b0",
"client-request-id": "fceadbcd-d55a-4bee-b2a9-fca6828053b0"
}
}
}
```

Can you guys help me get an idea of what I'm doing wrong?
(A guy in a Microsoft forum said it could be related to the tokens being on different versions, but I was not able to decode them to confirm)

Comment: If the token is successfully refreshed, you should be able to decode it, it is just a jwt (use https://jwt.io for example). If you cannot decode it, it may be truncated by one of your organization's servers (tool long)

Comment: I think this error might be due to sneding OAuth as Oauth instead of the bearer token that is Bearer of authorization header is a typo. The correct parameter should be like authorization: bearer {access_token}.